# JavaFX how do I make my text bold/ underline and add them in a separate outline box/square?

Tags: javafx

In my code, how do I make my text bold and underline and add them in a separate outline box/square?  Especially for "You are currently registered for" and "Current Credit Hours".  I tried adding the font weight and underline but it did not work and gave me an error that didn't make much sense.  If possible highlight what you added and as always, Thank you in advance.

This is the Main Class:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.Region;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;
import javafx.scene.text.FontPosture;
import javafx.scene.text.FontWeight;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.geometry.HPos;
import javafx.geometry.VPos;
import javafx.scene.layout.RowConstraints;
import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;


public class JavaFXRegister extends Application {

    GridPane grid = new GridPane();
    Label selectPromptLabel = new Label("Please select a course for which you 
    want to register");
    ComboBox<Course> coursesComboBox = new ComboBox<>();   
    Label confirmPromptLabel = new Label("");
    Label registeredCoursesPromptLabel = new Label("You are currently registered for");
    Label creditHourPromptLabel = new Label("Current total Credit Hours");            
    Label registeredCoursesLabel = new Label("");
    Label creditHoursLabel = new Label("0");

    Course choice;
    int totalCredit = 0;


    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

    /*
        grid.setHgap(0);
        grid.setVgap(500);

        grid.setGridLinesVisible(true);
    */
        RowConstraints row0 = new RowConstraints();
        RowConstraints row1 = new RowConstraints();
        RowConstraints row2 = new RowConstraints();
        RowConstraints row3 = new RowConstraints();
        RowConstraints row4 = new RowConstraints();


        row0.setPercentHeight(5);
        row1.setPercentHeight(50);
        row2.setPercentHeight(10);
        row3.setPercentHeight(5);
        row4.setPercentHeight(15);

        grid.getRowConstraints().addAll(row0, row1,row2, row3, row4);

        grid.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

        grid.setHgap(5);
        grid.setVgap(5);

        //Ron Added
        grid.setPadding(new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10));  

        grid.add(selectPromptLabel, 0, 0);
        grid.setHalignment(selectPromptLabel, HPos.LEFT);

        //Ron Added
        selectPromptLabel.setMinWidth(Region.USE_PREF_SIZE);


        coursesComboBox.getItems().addAll(
                new Course("IT4782"), 
                new Course("IT4784"),
                new Course("IT4786"),
                new Course("IT4789"),
                new Course("IT2230"),
                new Course("IT3345"),
                new Course("IT3349") );
        coursesComboBox.setMaxWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE);

        grid.add(coursesComboBox, 0, 1);
        grid.setValignment(coursesComboBox, VPos.TOP);

        confirmPromptLabel.setTextFill(Color.RED);

        grid.add(confirmPromptLabel, 0, 2);  
        grid.setHalignment(confirmPromptLabel, HPos.LEFT);
        grid.setValignment(confirmPromptLabel, VPos.TOP);

        grid.add(registeredCoursesPromptLabel, 0, 3);  
        grid.setHalignment(registeredCoursesPromptLabel, HPos.LEFT);
        grid.setValignment(registeredCoursesPromptLabel, VPos.TOP);

        grid.add(creditHourPromptLabel, 1, 3);  
        grid.setHalignment(creditHourPromptLabel, HPos.LEFT);   
        grid.setValignment(creditHourPromptLabel, VPos.TOP);

        grid.add(registeredCoursesLabel, 0, 4);
        grid.setHalignment(registeredCoursesLabel, HPos.LEFT);   
        grid.setValignment(registeredCoursesLabel, VPos.TOP);
        registeredCoursesLabel.setStyle("-fx-background-color: #fff600;");

        grid.add(creditHoursLabel, 1, 4); 
        grid.setHalignment(creditHoursLabel, HPos.LEFT);   
        grid.setValignment(creditHoursLabel, VPos.TOP);
        creditHoursLabel.setStyle("-fx-background-color: #fff600;");

        Scene scene = new Scene(grid, 500, 500, Color.RED);

        primaryStage.setTitle("JavaFX Register for Course");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();


        coursesComboBox.setOnAction(e -> {

            //Ron Added 
            coursesComboBox.getValue();
            choice = coursesComboBox.getValue();

            //Ron added
            String setCode = choice.toString();
            // Update display of registered courses 
            if(choice.getIsRegisteredFor()){
                confirmPromptLabel.setText("**Invalid** \n" + "You are already registered for " + setCode);
                return;
            }
            // Update display of the total credit hours 
            if(totalCredit >= 9){
                confirmPromptLabel.setText("**Invalid** \n" + "You can't register for anymore courses.");
                return;
            }
            //display message
            confirmPromptLabel.setText("You have registered for " + setCode );
            registeredCoursesLabel.setText(registeredCoursesLabel.getText() + 
      setCode + "\n");
            totalCredit += 3;
            creditHoursLabel.setText(totalCredit + "");
            choice.setIsRegisteredFor(true);
        });
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

Course Class

```
package javafxregisterforcourse;

public class Course {

    private String code = "";
    private boolean isRegisterdFor = false;

    public Course(String code){
        this.code = code;
    }

    public void setCode(String code){
        this.code = code;
    }

    public String getCode() {
        return this.code;
    }

    public void setIsRegisteredFor(boolean trueOrFalse){
        this.isRegisterdFor = trueOrFalse;
    }

    public boolean getIsRegisteredFor() {
        return this.isRegisterdFor;
    } 

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return this.getCode();
    }
}
```

Comment: you should show what exactly you have tried and the error that took place, regardless it made sense for you or not. And take consideration of kleopatra's comment – not only about your question here, but also about what you are trying to achieve (is it really necessary to make those underlined bold?)

Comment: Using Bold text in my code to see the output better with those who have a hard time seeing.  Not shouting as that is just a perspective in some peoples eyes.